# Azure DevOps Field References

Tags: azure, hyperlink, devops

I'm trying to auto generate a links based on an ID field to an external web portal. For example, I have Customer_Ticket_ID=123 and I know that the details related to that item, outside of devops, would be `www.theticketingsyste.com?customer_ticket_id=123`. It would be really helpful to autogenerate the link, given the ID field. Is there a way to do this? I was thinking simply just a hidden static field for the "www.theticketingsyste.com?customer_ticket_id=" part of the URL and then concatenated with the user entered ID field...

Comment: [Use links to view dependencies and track related work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-work-items-support-traceability?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and [Reference guide for link types used in Azure DevOps and Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops#hyperlink)

Comment: Those are static links, though. I am hoping to build dynamic links based on a user entered field.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the question, but since I'm researching a similar problem at the moment, here is a solution for Azure DevOps Server:

If you're on the Azure DevOps Server variant and managing your workitems through xml files, you can use the following syntax for the described usecase:

```
<Control Label="External ID" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="My.External.ID">
                <LabelText>
                  <Text>
                    <Link UrlRoot="https://my.base.url.here/" UrlPath="{0}">
                      <Param Index="0" Value="My.External.ID" />
                    </Link>
                            This will be the actual label text that is the clickable link
                    </Text>
                </LabelText>
              </Control>
```

This will add a clickable and highlighted link in the label of a field (refname: My.External.ID) where you're storing the external ID. It combines the UrlRoot and UrlPath to form the final Url. The Control needs to be embedded in the FORM section of the xml template, in the Layout and/or Weblayout sections, as usual, when defining the workitem layout.